# Generating urls and post data in c

Tags: c, curl, query-string

After quite a bit of searching, I have been unable to find a good way to dynamically generate query strings and x-www-form-urlencoded post data. I am writing a library that will do this quite frequently. If need be, I can write a utility to build these strings, but I would really like to avoid re-invinting the wheel.

Are there any libraries, or common practices for dynamically generating query strings in C?

I am using libcurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a little bit of Google-fu ([`c encode query string -C# -objective`](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+encode+query+string+-C%23+-objective)), but I ended up with:

`libccgi` - [C CGI Library 1.1](http://libccgi.sourceforge.net/doc.html)

Specifically, its function [`CGI_encode_query()`](http://libccgi.sourceforge.net/doc.html#CGI_encode_query)